# consultas mysql ignorar tildes

Tags: php, sql

Quería consultar si existe alguna manera de realizar búsquedas dentro de un documento de manera que no tenga en cuenta las tildes de las palabra. Es decir, si quiero buscar la palabra "camión" en el texto, que pueda hacerlo escribiendo "camion" en la ventana de búsqueda.

ejemplo tengo esta parte de mi codigo PHP 
Código:

```
SELECT * FROM anuncio WHERE tipo like  '%".$busqueda."%';
```

si busco "Comida", "mida", "omi".... funciona todo perfecto, pero si busco "comida" con C minuscula no detecta, como puedo hacer para q la consulta me la arroje sin importar sean mayusculas minusculas o acentos? gracias!!

Comment: Para mayúsculas y minúsculas usa UPPER en ambos lados.

Comment: Usando dql de Symfony el comando LIKE funciona de la forma que tu quieres, si Laravel usa Doctrine como ORM, debe funcionar también.

Comment: @ArmandoRodríguezAcosta Laravel NO usa doctrine sino Eloquent

Answer (score 1):

Para la búsqueda en la base omitiendo las tildes use:

```
SELECT * FROM `anuncio ` WHERE tipo like  '%camion%' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Así buscará *camión* y *camion*.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que hablas de dos temas: la cuestión de las letras con tilde y la de las mayúsculas y minúsculas. Yo tuve bastantes problemas con ambos puntos en una base de datos de MySQL bastante antigua, y los resolví codificando todos los datos susceptibles de tener literales (char, varchar, text...) en UTF-8. En la estructura de la tabla, tenía esos campos con una codificación latin (no recuerdo exactamente cual de las latin era, pero no era UTF-8).

Modifiqué la estructura, poniendo el cotejamiento a utf8-general-ci (lo de ci se refiere a Case Insensitive, es decir, insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas). Si son muchas tablas, con estructuras grandes, puede ser un poco engorroso retocarlas, pero es mejor.

Con eso se me resolvieron los dos problemas al mismo tiempo. A lo mejor te gusta leer el artículo en https://eldesvandejose.com/2018/09/14/poniendo-mysql-en-utf-8/, porque te detalla como configurar el motor de MySQL para que UTF-8 sea el cotejamiento por defecto.